# PostgreSQL: Could not connect to server even though it's running!

Tags: database, cron, postgresql

I wonder if you could possibly help me. I have installed PostgreSQL and I have tried running various checks to ensure it is running and I know it is.

Here are the results of searching for the postgres process:

```
root@myserver [~]# ps aux | grep post
    root     12989  0.0  0.0  61192   736 pts/0    S<+  18:42   0:00 grep post
    postgres 19116  0.0  0.0 120732  3352 ?        S<   Mar14   0:00 /usr/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
    postgres 19122  0.0  0.0 109908   772 ?        S<   Mar14   0:00 postgres: logger process
    postgres 19124  0.0  0.0 120732   996 ?        S<   Mar14   0:00 postgres: writer process
    postgres 19125  0.0  0.0 110912   700 ?        S<   Mar14   0:00 postgres: stats buffer process
    postgres 19126  0.0  0.0 110100   876 ?        S<   Mar14   0:00 postgres: stats collector process
```

This to me is solid enough evidence that it is infact running but here is the exact error I am getting:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This comes in an email when the DB cache attempts to update.

Help is much appreciated and thanks for any response!

Comment: You need to answer **both** of the questions psql posed to you (Is the server running, **and** is it accepting connections on that socket?).  If you can answer yes to *both* questions please post your server logs  - they may tell us what's going on.

Comment: You can also try to connect through a local socket, although as voretaq7 says there's more information to fill up

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. Sorry to sound amateur but how do I check whether it is accepting connections on that socket or not? Server is definitely running (postmaster (pid 19126 19125 19124 19122 19116) is running...)

Comment: @Chris What does `ls -l /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` say?  If it's not found, then try `ls -l /tmp/.s.PGSQL.*`?  My postgresql is configured to put the socket in `/var/run/postgresql/s.PGSQL.5432`, look there?

Comment: This should be a comment, but...

please post /etc/postgresql/relevant_version_number/main/pg_hba.conf in your answer or wherever that file is located. 
You don't say what version of PostgreSQL you are running, though it is probably not important here.

Comment: @DerfK that might well have solved my problem however I will have to wait until the next email I guess... the socket was not showing in /tmp folder so I went to the postgresql configuration and reconfigured it so instead of assuming the default it uses /tmp. Now I can find the socket within the folder. Your help is much appreciate and I will rate up all of the above as they were very helpful.